# Stripe API Infinite Loop

Tags: jquery, infinite-loop, stripe-payments

I'm encountering an infinite loop when working through this Stripe tutorial (https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/forms).

```
$j('#payment-form').submit(function(){

    var $form = $j(this);

    $j('#submit',$form).prop('disabled',true);

    Stripe.card.createToken($form,stripeResponseHandler);

    return false;

});

// Stripe Callback

function stripeResponseHandler(status,response){

    var $form = $j('#payment-form');

    if(response.error){

        /* Show the errors on the form */

        $j('.payment-errors',$form).addClass('msg error_msg').text(response.error.message);
        $j('#submit',$form).prop('disabled', false);

    } else {

        var token = response.id;

        $form.append($j('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
        $form.get(0).submit();

    }

};
```

The createToken response handler says to use $form.get(0).submit() to re-submit the form without re-triggering the initial submit listener, but I get a console error saying that $form.get(..).submit is not a function.

Changing $form.get(0).submit() to just $form.submit() starts up the loop.

Following some other suggestions I'd found, I added a check for the token in the submit listener that returns true if the token is present. This breaks the loop, but the form is never submitted.

```
$j('#payment-form').submit(function(){

    if(typeof $j('input[name="stripeToken"]').val() !== 'undefined'){
        return true;
    }

    var $form = $j(this);

    $j('#submit',$form).prop('disabled',true);

    Stripe.card.createToken($form,stripeResponseHandler);

    return false;

});
```

I'm working with jQuery 1.11.1.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: try passing `this` instead of `$form` to `createToken`

Comment: No luck, still looping or throwing TypeError at $form.get(0).submit()...

Comment: Why isn't $form.get(0) working as expected?

Comment: check the docs, something isn't right and docs are good

Comment: I'm following tutorial directly from the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by changing the id of my submit button from "submit".

I don't really understand why this was causing the problem, so if any one can elaborate, that would be great.

Comment: I believe it's because their JS uses the dis/en-abled of the submit button as a marker for whether or not to get a new token or submit the form finally. If you were to use a text input for the token rather than hidden, you'll see it get new tokens infinitely.

Answer (score 1):

Another way that I found to get rid of the Infinite loop is with this line:

```
$form[0].submit();
```

It saved me and I Hope it saves you. :)

Comment: This works only if you have 1 form on the page. If you have other forms, like a search box in the header, you'll have to change that index.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the new Stripe Elements library (part of Stripe.js) and was having the loop as well.

Instead of following the examples line by line, I used **jQuery** to attach the event handler to the submit event, something like:

```
var form = $('#payment-form')
form.on('submit', function() { ...
```

If you did it like me, if you then use `form.submit()` anywhere else on your code, you will attempt to submit the form using jQuery, which will trigger an endless loop because it will trigger jQuery's submit event handler on the form again and again (just watch your devtools network tab go crazy).

The solution is to submit without jQuery, using `form[0].submit()`, remembering that `form` was a jQuery object and `form[0]` gets you the native form element. This solved the loop for me.